# difference between Map and MapWhen branch in asp.net core Middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

When to use Map and MapWhen branch in asp.net core middleware while we are authenticating request.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Map("", (appBuilder) =>
    {
        appBuilder.Run(async (context) => {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
        });
    });

    app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Query.ContainsKey(""), (appBuilder) =>
    {
        appBuilder.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
        });

    });
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Map` could branch the request based on match of the specified request path only. `MapWhen` is more powerful and allows branching the request based on result of specified predicate that operates with current `HttpContext` object.
As far `HttpContext` contains all information about HTTP request, `MapWhen` allows you to use very specific conditions for branching request pipeline.

Any `Map` call could be easily converted to `MapWhen`, but not vice versa. For example this `Map` call:

```
app.Map("SomePathMatch", (appBuilder) =>
{
    appBuilder.Run(async (context) => {

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
    });
});
```

is equivalent to the following `MapWhen` call:

```
app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("SomePathMatch"), (appBuilder) =>
{
    appBuilder.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("");
    });
});
```

So answering your question "When to use Map and MapWhen branch": use `Map` when you branch request based on request path only. Use `MapWhen` when you branch request based on other data from the HTTP request.

Comment: CodeFuller this is not entirely true, see @alex-lorimer 's answer below with an example in my comment.

Answer (score 42):

The accepted answer is helpful, but not entirely accurate. Apart from the predicate logic, key differences between `Map` and `MapWhen` are that `Map` will add [MapMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapMiddleware.cs) to the pipeline (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapExtensions.cs#L50)), while `MapWhen` will add [MapWhenMiddleware](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapWhenMiddleware.cs) to the pipeline (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapWhenExtensions.cs#L53)). The effect of this is that `Map` will update the `Request.Path` and `Request.PathBase` to account for branching based on path (trimming the matched path segment off `Request.Path` and appending it to `Request.PathBase`), while a seemingly equivalent `MapWhen` predicate will not. This affects anything downstream that uses the path, such as routing!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This is especially true if the middleware inside the map is expecting the first part of the path. For example, if `UseMvc()` expects the prefix `/api` in the route, `app.Map("/api", builder => builder.UseMvc())` will not work. Instead it's better to use `app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), ... );`

Comment: This answer explains a very important aspect of using `.Map(`