# end point not working in .netcore 2.1, why?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

This is a very simple question about why is this happening.

First of all, I've got a .net core 2.1 project, and I need 3 extra endpoints, so this is my code:

```
        app.Map("/h1", handle1);
        app.Map("/h1/h2", handle2);
        app.Map("/h1/h3", handle3);
```

in the Configure method. handle1, handl2 and handle3 are custom methods to write different things on localhost:port/h1, localhost:port/h1/h2 and localhost:port/h1/h3.

However this is not working, because I get at localhost:port/h1/h2 the same result than for the other two, so localhost:port/h1 is correct but localhost:port/h1/h2 and localhost:port/h1/h3 are showing localhost:port/h1 which is not correct.

I have tried a few things, and this is kind of working:

```
    app.Map("/h1", handle1);
    app.Map("/h/h2", handle2);
    app.Map("/h/h3", handle3);
```

questions are why? and how do I make it so localhost:port/h1 and localhost:port/h1/h2 and localhost:port/h1/h3 work?

Update:

I tried this and it works, but I don't get why

```
    app.Map("/h1/h2", handle2);
    app.Map("/h1/h3", handle3);
    app.Map("/h1", handle1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the order of checking that's important.

Say your url is:

```
url = "/h1/h2/somethingcool"
```

The way your map is built up is:

```
[ 
  "/h1"
  "/h1/h2",
  "/h1/h3"
]
```

So when your map is looped this happens(pseudocode):

```
for(map.entries() : entry) {
    if(url.startsWith(entry.url) {
       entry.doTheThing(url);
       break;
    }
}
```

so when we patch values in there:

```
url = "/h1/h2/somethingcool"
foreach value in [ "/h1", "/h1/h2", "/h1/h3" ] put it in entry
loop 1:
   entry = "/h1"
   if([url]"/h1/h2/somethingcool" starts with [entry]"/h1") 
     do the route
     abort looping 
Loop is aborted
stopping processing other array items.
```

Now if we take your other map that does work, we get the behaviour we expect.

```
url = "/h1/h2/somethingcool"
foreach value in [ "/h1/h3", "/h1/h2", "/h1" ] put it in entry
loop 1:
   entry = "/h1/h3"
   if([url]"/h1/h2/somethingcool" starts with [entry]"/h1/h3") 
     it did not match. Continue looping.
   if([url]"/h1/h2/somethingcool" starts with [entry]"/h1/h2") 
     do the route
     abort looping 
Loop is aborted
stopping processing other array items.
```

I hope this helps you understand the logic behind the process. It all boils down to that the url is matched if it starts with it, not if it's a perfect match.

Comment: is this meant to o be a .net core bug or there is a reason behind?

Comment: @Iria According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48001921/1356107, this is the default expected behaviour. If just a string is supplied for path, it's checked if an url starts with that path. And then it loops through its map of urls and halts on the first match. fifo